# laravel composer update broke my site - all dates are displaying as today

Tags: laravel

Is anyone having this issue? Last night I ran composer update and all my dates on my production site are displaying as today's date instead of the stored value in the database.

Everything is displaying correctly on my local machine.

I received this code at one point:

```
include(/home/forge/essentialstudiomanager.com/vendor/composer/../nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
```

I converted back to an older Laravel install and that didn't fix it so I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Try updating to `5.5.39` or `5.6.11`. Seems there was an issue with Carbon: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23465

Comment: I updated to 5.6.11 but the issue is still there. I am trying to run composer dump-autoload to see if this helps but digital ocean is giving me some problems so I have to work this out first.

Comment: composer dump-autoload didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know exactly what happened but to fix this I had to update my digital ocean droplet. Doing this though started throwing a permissions error so I had to adjust my permissions on my storage folder and now everything is good.